# How can the 'mail' command be used?

Tags: macos, terminal, unix, email

I've had my first Mac for about five months now. Though, even when I was a full-on Windows user, I never did things through a command line; I was pretty much for the GUI all-the-way..

But now that I have my Mac, I'm interested in learning a little about the Terminal and the commands used in it. So far I've learned how to do minor things, like moving, renaming, and deleting files, ect. But now I want to go for something different, like the mail command.

So tonight I figured out how to send mail to myself through the 'mail' command. But now I'm curious and asking if there's a way to send e-mail to people using say, Yahoo or Hotmail.

Sorry if this is a basic question, but I'm new and curious. Thanks.

Comment: Technically, GUI-all-the-way is also the Mac way. What you are learning is the **Unix** way.

Comment: `man mail`. 'nuff said.

Answer (score 4):

It you want to send an email to a given address put it as an argument to the `mail` command:

```
mail -s "Some subject" toaddress@example.com
```

see `man mail` for other options

Any text you type after issuing the command you can enter the text for your mail directly in the terminal. To end mail text entry, enter a new line with a single `.`.

Do note that this just queues the mail for sending as if your mac were a functioning mail server. Local delivery to local accounts is easy to set up, to set up a working mail server that connects to the internet requires some more advanced set up as well as a relationship with someone else that operates a mail relay. This isn't a client that works directly with mail services like gmail / yahoo / hotmail or iCloud (MobileMe).